# Ruby on Rails Could not find "config/databases/sqlite3.yml"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble creating a new Rails app, where it used to work fine.

Using mysql or postgres doesn't solve the problem. The output is pretty the same with every database type.

Creating a new app goes with a first warning about sqlite.

```
rails new myapp --quiet
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/libros/myapp/.git/
Could not find "config/databases/sqlite3.yml" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
/home/libros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates
```

Then trying to do some base things with app causes another errors.

```
rails db:create
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:create' (see --tasks)
/home/libros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/home/libros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/libros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/libros/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Do u have checked an database.yml file exists in the path config/database.yml?

Comment: also verify that database is installed in u r system? which OS u r using?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10, database is installed and database.yml is missing.

Comment: Can u access the  sqlite3 directly in console? Go to app folder in console just type  sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall sqllite3 and try to install it
again.

**unistall**
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sqlite3
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sqlite3

**install**
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sqlite3

create a file in database.yml inside the config folder

and paste below code

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

save and restart the application.

Comment: Somehow some rails files were missing. I've just reinstalled whole rails and it worked. Thanks anyway.